# Pandas dataframe query not finding value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an issue that I can't understand why the value I'm searching doesn't appear to exist in dataframe.

I've started with combining couple numerical columns in my original dataframe and assigned to a new column. And then I've extracted a list of unique values from that combined column

```
~snip

    self.df['Flitch'] = self.df['Blast'].map(
                str) + "-" + self.df['Bench'].map(str)

    self.flitches = self.df['Flitch'].unique()

~snip
```

Now slightly further in the code I need to get earliest date values corresponding to these unique identifiers. So I go and run a query on the dataframe:

```
~snip

def get_dates(self):
        '''Extracts mining and loading dates from filtered dataframe'''

        loading_date, mining_date = [],[]

        #loop through all unique flitch ids and get their mining
        #and loading dates

        for flitch in self.flitches:

            temp = self.df.query('Activity=="MINE"')
            temp = temp.query(f'Flitch=={flitch}')
            mining = temp['PeriodStartDate'].min()
            mining_date.append(mining)   

~snip
```

...and I get nothing. I can't understand why. I mean, I'm comparing the data extracted from the column to that same column and I'm not getting any matches.

I've gone and manually checked that the list of unique ids is populated correctly.

I've checked that dataframe I'm running query on does indeed has those same flitch ids.

I've manually checked for several random values from `self.flitches` list and it comes back as `False` every time.

Before I've combined those two columns and used only 'Blast' as identifier, everything worked perfectly, but now I'm not sure what is happening.

Here for example I've printed the `self.flitches` list:

```
['5252-528' '5251-528' '3030-492' '8235-516' '7252-488' '7251-488'
 '2351-588' '5436-588' '1130-624' '5233-468' '1790-516' '6301-552'
 '6302-552' '5444-576' '2377-564' '2380-552' '2375-564' '5253-528'
 '2040-468' '2378-564' '1132-624' '1131-624' '6314-540' '7254-488'
 '7253-488' '8141-480' '7250-488']
```

And here is data from `self.df['Flitch']` column:

```
173     5252-528
174     5251-528
175     5251-528
176     5251-528
177     5251-528
178     5251-528
180     3030-492
181     3030-492
182     3030-492
183     3030-492
...
```

It looks like they have to match but they don't...

Comment: I think you missed the qoutes around the flitch values: `f"Flitch=='{flitch}'"`

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew it would be something this simple!